# How to assign/read variable from MATLAB engine with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I'm trying to use [MATLAB engine](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-net.html) with .NET. Problem is, I don't seem to be able to read/assign variables. The closest I got to reading is:

```
using dynamic matlab = MATLABEngine.StartMATLAB();
double[,] M = matlab.rot(v, Math.PI / 180 * 45);
System.Console.WriteLine(matlab.r);
```

where `rot` is defined like:

```
function M = rot(v, theta)
    R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
    M = R * v;
    r = rand(1);
end
```

All I see in the log is:

```
MathWorks.MATLAB.Types.MATLABPackage
```

For assigning variables, I tried the following, none of which worked:

```
matlab.x = 1;
matlab.workspace.x = 1;
matlab["x"] = 1;
matlab.workspace["x"] = 1;
```

Comment: have u checked this bro https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-net-from-matlab-an-overview.html or this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Matlab.ToolKit @saqx1